# invalid sharepoint session objects

Tags: c#, sharepoint, session-variables

Ok I'm new to SharePoint and ASP, so bear with me...

I want to persist objects to the session array for maintaining stuff between postbacks.  I enabled the session array in my web.config file, and everything works fine if I use basic value types or objects that are part of the .NET framework.

But if I try and save an instance of an object that I define the class for, I get an error message "An unexpected error has occurred.", even though I can step through the program without any errors being thrown.

What do I have to do to save my objects to the session array?

---

Edit:

So after starting the callstack as suggested, I get the following error:

> Unable to serialize the session state.
>   In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode,
>   ASP.NET will serialize the session
>   state objects, and as a result
>   non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not
>   permitted. The same restriction
>   applies if similar serialization is
>   done by the custom session state store
>   in 'Custom' mode.

I suppose I could serialize my objects... is there a setting in the config file to make it not require SQL Server?

Comment: get more information about your error:
http://www.planettutorials.com/Blog/tabid/59/ID/13/How-to-show-detailed-Error-and-Stack-Trace-in-SharePoint.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your custom class with the [Serializeable] attribute.  If your class has fields that are references to other custom classes, make sure those have the [Serializeable] attribute as well

Answer (score 0):

Is the SharePoint session HttpModule enabled in web.config?

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

if you set Callstack="true" on your web.config file you can probably see the "[Error Reason] because Session State is disabled"